# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() any solution

Tags: wordpress

This is my code working on plugin need to insert 2 arrays into phpmyadmin but something wrong with forach loop of php...any solution.... any alternate solution how to insert?

```
    if (isset($_POST['addvenue'])) {


<?php echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST['RoomTilte'],true)."</pre>";
echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST['Capacity'],true)."</pre>";

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//database connection
mysql_select_db("ossd");
$a=array($_POST['RoomTitle']);
if (is_array($a))
{
    echo"yes it is array";
foreach ($_POST['RoomTitle'] as $row=>$name)

{

    $Roomtitle = $name;

    $Capacity = $_POST['Capacity'][$row];
    $RoomTitle= mysql_real_escape_string($name);

    $Capacity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Capacity'][$row]);

    $order = "INSERT INTO wp_ossd_venue
        (RoomTitle,Capacity)
        VALUES
        (".$RoomTitle.",".$Capacity.")";

    $result = mysql_query($order);

}
}
if($result){
    echo("<br>Succesfully Added");
} else{
    echo("<br>Fail... Error");
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Would be much easier if you use the wordpress $wpdb class to work with the database.

Refer the wordpress codex for following function:

```
<?php $wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows